# how to get the quotelineitem field in quote object while creating vf page

Tags: visualforce, soql, quote, quotelineitem

Can any help me out  on this.Im creating a visual force pages related to quote , quotelineitems and custom object named as competitor.now i would like to get the field names of quotelineitems ans competitor on Quote object.Competitor has a lookup relation to Quote object.

When i refer with __c or__r it gives me an Error
when i use :
1)   Error: Invalid field QuoteLineItem for SObject Quote ,

2)Error   Error: Invalid field QuoteLineItem__r for SObject Quote

3)Error Error: Invalid field competitor__c for SObject Quote

Answer (score 0):

There is no Field Called QuoteLineItem in Sobject,
There is a field Quote in Object QuoteLineItem.
The Same thing to Competitor,